# The meaning of a compound verb

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "smear out" mean in the following sentence? I didn't find it in any dictionary.

> However, small though the length is,
>   it is nevertheless finite, and this finite extent is the bridge
>   between quantum theory and general relativity in that it
>   **smears out** the quantum fluctuations

Comment: Hello, amjahan. Please include the definitions from those dictionaries you did find it in. // I'd assume it is non-standard for 'smooth out'.

Answer (score 2):

It means that this is the length-scale at which quantum fluctuations are no longer relevant. What you would "see" above this length-scale is the net effect of many smaller quantum effects combined, so you see them "smeared" together.